What Icons do you use in libreoffice draw for network diagrams? and how do you add them?
I wanted to use libreoffice draw to draw network diagrams.
I searched a little and found out that there is an extension called VRT ( https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/vrt-network-equipment )
Also I've heard that Libreoffice Draw should be able to use the cisco eps icons if I convert them to svg ( https://www.peteredstrom.se/how-to-import-cisco-network-symbols-in-libreoffice-draw ). I was wondering what you could suggest me to use if you used different themes/icons.
